# How to link to page of an outer pdf document?

Tags: cross-referencing, pdf, links

How can I create a link from a PDF-Reference to another external PDF? I want to reference a source and when you click on it, the document should jump to the bibliography like normal. An then i want to put all sources from the bibliography to a seperate folder as PDF-Files. 
Then when I click to a source itself in the bibliography I want that my PDF opens the book or what ever is referenced and the correct page with the marked text.
Does somebody know if that is possible in latex in some way? Maybe with a kind of hyperlink to the PDF and some parameters to directly open the correct page?
Thank you !

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Hyperlinks referring to URLs works when referring to local files too. However, this implies that the folder structure in your local OS should not be later modified (or links will brake). It might also be difficult to make this work for people on other systems (the articles you refer to might not be reachable with the exact same path on their systems.) As for linking to a specific page of a pdf, I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

When i give somebody my work i alway put a micro sd card at the end of my paper work. And on the micro SD card i have my Tex files and a source folder with the PDF, so the folder will alway be in the same location. 
But at first i really want to know if that is possible. Because normally when you reference a book, you have to open it and so search for the quotation to compare the information of the referenced book with the information in the text. And with such kind of link you directly reach the correct location of your quotation.